# Posting to user's wall - difference between wall and feed?

Tags: facebook

I've set up Facebook login on my site, and have done a couple of test wall posts when certain user actions occur.  I tested it on my FB account, and the posts turned up on my wall (good).

Immediately I had a couple of friends email saying, 'how do I turn these notifications off, they're filling up my feed'.

I'm guessing this isn't a good way to promote my app - it'll piss people off. Unless I have an option at the time of the app action for the user to say 'yes, post to my wall.'

I notice that my posts were also coming up in the activity ticker (on the right of your profile page), and that a lot of game apps post player activity there - is it possible to just post to that and not to the wall?  If so, what do I code instead of "/me/feed", "post"?

Thanks

Comment: what you see in the feeds are the activities of your friends including the wall posts. so technically what you asking is not possible, If I understood your question

Answer (score 0):

In the activity ticker it is actually the updates from the Users or pages or apps are displayed which actually come from , if you go back to their wall and see, their respective wall.

Feeds are usually the updates and those also come from wall.

One thing which you can do is when providing permission to your app you can make it visible to you only(Only me option) so that none of your friends gets it in his/her feed.

Otherwise there is no other way for now.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly making a post through graph API use Fb.ui feed method. This will open a popup dialog which user can accept to be published on wall or cancel:

```
FB.ui(
  {
    method: 'feed',
    name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
    link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
    picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
    caption: 'Reference Documentation',
    description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface with users.'
  },
  function(response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {
      alert('Post was published.');
    } else {
      alert('Post was not published.');
    }
  }
);
```

note:all links here should point to domain specified by you in canvas url

A better approach would be to use [open graph actions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/opengraph/) instead a just posting a story on wall. Open graph actions are seen in Activity section of your timeline. The stories are small hence does not seem like spamming user wall. If the number of posts is high it is aggregated/clubbed together.

Comment: Thanks for your replies guys.  So game appscreate custom actions to display user activity, right?  My app is actually a song list web app that I use Facebook to log in to, and I want to publish a user's activity when they request a song.  So their first name, 'requested ' name-of-song' at 'my-web-app-name' - which is the info that I successfully got on the wall post.  Is it possible to populate a custom action with this same type of data?

Comment: yes! in your app setting go to Open Grap section in left menu there you can declare an action 'request' and object 'song' and then there are many more steps though u'll be able to figure out that

Comment: Thanks Vishwesh - just wanted to know it's possible before spending hours going down the wrong path, although that's always a learning experience too.  Cheers mate.

Comment: I'm unsure it can be done the way I want.  My song list page is dynamic, with different songs displayed depending on what the user searches for.  It looks like open graph depends on static og tags on each page that it uses to populate the activity display.  Do you also think this is the case?

Comment: No you can have dynamic og tags. When you post and action you can send parameters in your link so your song would be **song='applink?songname'.songname.'&parameter2='.parameter2**... and so on. and in your landing page in og Meta tags you wont hardcode values but use $_GET['songname'], $GET['parameter2'] and so on.

Comment: Ahh.  Do you have control over where the feed ends up? Some info I've read says it might end up on their wall, whereas I only want it in the activity feed.

Comment: Yes it will show up in activity section of users timeline. If number of post are high it will be clubbed as one story in a box on his timeline. But it does not seem like spamming as a normal wall posts would.